# swiping the notification causes the service to stop working android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, localnotification, notificationmanager

Currently the notification appears on the set time and at an interval of one day. But when I swipe the notification to the right or left or remove the notification from the notification bar then the alarm isn't repeating the next day and the notification keeps popping up every now and then if i keep swiping it.

> **setNotification function specified in Main Activity**

```
public void setNotification(int hour, int minutes, int ampm){

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minutes);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    if(ampm == 1) {
        calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);
    }else{
        calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);
    }

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, notificationReceiver.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, myIntent,0);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 60000 ,pendingIntent);

    SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor = mPrefs.edit();
    alarm_set_flag = mEditor.putBoolean(tag, true).commit();

}
```

> **alarmService.JAVA**

```
package com.silveroakhealth.tranquil;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.IBinder;

/**
 * Created by Varun K Nair on 7/7/2017.
 */

public class alarmService extends Service {
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0)
    {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        Uri sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+this.getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.bell);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
        Intent deleteIntent = new Intent();
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,0);
        PendingIntent clearIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,deleteIntent,0);

        Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("Tranquil")
                .setContentText("Pause. It’s time to be mindful!")
                .setSmallIcon(getNotificationIcon())
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setDeleteIntent(clearIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.notification))
                .setSound(sound)
                .build();
        notificationManager.notify(0,notification);
    }

    private int getNotificationIcon() {
        boolean useWhiteIcon = (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP);
        return useWhiteIcon ? R.drawable.notification_sil : R.drawable.notification_icon;
    }

}
```

> **notificatioReciever.JAVA**

```
package com.silveroakhealth.tranquil;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

/**
 * Created by Varun K Nair on 7/7/2017.
 */

public class notificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent service1 = new Intent(context, alarmService.class);
        context.startService(service1);

    }
}
```

> **Manifest.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.silveroakhealth.tranquil">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name=".alarmService"
            android:enabled="true" />

        <receiver android:name=".notificationReceiver"
            android:enabled="true">
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Can someone please tell me whats going wrong and how to repeat the alarm every day without cancelling it.

Comment: I think you dont need BroadcastReceiver. Use `pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(MainActivity.this, 0, myIntent,0);` instead of `pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, myIntent,0);`

Comment: also change `Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, alarmService.class);`

Comment: @MuraliPrajapati Broadcast receiver and service i have used so that it can trigger the notification even if the phone is locked or if the app isnt running in the background and the problem im facing isnt going to be resolved I guess. Probably will have to use GCM based push notification services itself. But it also causes the problem of internet connectivity for push notification  to work.